# Usage of Kotlin internal declaration from different module while integrating Stripe in Android

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, stripe-payments, androidx

Following the [guidline](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/sdk/android), I'm integrating Stripe in Android. In the step 4 they use `TerminalLifecycleObserver` in Application class. I've followed all the steps above and also tried more brief guidline from their GitHub [repository](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-android). But after all still getting the error **Usage of Kotlin internal declaration from different module** on `TerminalLifecycleObserver` in my Application class. Here's the screenshot showing the error and exception logs.
[image]

Comment: what version of Stripe Terminal Android SDK are you using?

Comment: ah looks like v2.0.0 ... any particular beta version of v2.0.0 you're on?

Comment: It's `implementation "com.stripe:stripeterminal:2.0.0"`

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you ever resolve this? I've followed the stripe docs to a T.... or so I thought

Answer (score 8):

I'm posting this now since I've just found myself in the same predicament with no answer to this post that keeps coming up.

The error `Usage of Kotlin internal declaration from different module` is actually an Intellij's inspection set with level `Error`. The code is fine; it's the inspection level that is preventing you from running the code.

To execute your application, you can either lower the severity of the inspection or disable it altogether.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-12493/Usage-of-Kotlin-internal-declaration-from-different-module-more...

To lower the severity from Error to Warning, all you need to do is to go to `File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Kotlin > Usage of Kotlin internal declarations from Java` and then change its severity level.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is where severity level of this inspection can be changed:
Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Kotlin -> Java interop issues -> usage of Kotlin Internal declarations from Java

[image]